# Save action for HTML editor in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I know I can set `save action` for `java/javascript/c++` editor. Is there any way I can set-up Save action for `HTML` or other text editor.

Comment: wow I stumble upon my question again.

Answer (score 0):

As of now (eclipse neon.2), there are no save actions for HTML files.
I also tries opening these files in with different editors, which have save actions (like the JavaScript or PHP Editors), but the save action is not triggered when saving HTML files.

The only manual 'workaround' is to use Window -> Preferences -> Web -> HTML Files -> Editor to do some settings and format the files manually with [STRG]+[SHIFT]+[F] (default Format command shortcut).